# post is not showing more than 3949 words

Tags: posts, publish

I am writing a post which is more than 5000 words. When i publish it, only 3949 words are showing and rest of them disappeared.

Is there any limitation or words limit for the post ?

Could you please assist me on this to fix the issue.

Comment: This sounds like a niche issue, possibly a limitation added by a plugin or inherent to the theme. Try switching to the default theme to see if the issue persists and disabling all plugins to narrow down what may be causing this.

Comment: Or posted form size limit

Comment: Hello howdy_McGee, thanks for writing back. I found the issue. Actually i am writing my post in Hindi language ( as a indian) and that is causing issue here. I tried with posting content in english and worked fine. How can i fix such issue, i.e. written other than english